# Buying Legendary Blacksmithing Plans

Tags: diablo-iii

I was lucky enough to find a Legendary Plan the other night (Harvest Moon)... I noticed it had a sell value, which got me to wondering, "Can I buy these in the AH?". When I looked, however, I could only find higher level plans. Does that mean that:

A. You can't sell lower level Legendary Plans
  B. There were just none available at the time
  C. I am a big dummy, and was looking in the wrong place

Which is it? Or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks @fbueckert, didn't even realize I'd messed up the formatting....

Comment: Almost guaranteed it was C), I'm sorry to say.  There would be no reason Blizzard would restrict pre-level 60 items.  I'd guess you were looking in the wrong area, but you found the higher level plans.  It may be that the plan you found is not in the list at the bottom due to too many items.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your auction house search that didn't find any?  My guess is that you have the filter set to only show higher level recipes.

Comment: I can't atm... But later when I am home I can.....

Comment: @bwarner: There is no level filter for blacksmith plans

Comment: I'm such a tool, I don't know what the hell I was doing. What an idiot...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can buy or sell any blacksmith plan in the Auction House, except for the account bound Plan of Herding. They are listed in alphabetic order not level (annoyingly, there is no way to change this) but if you already found higher level plans, then you should be on the right screen to search for Harvest Moon as well.

It is possible that there is none available at the time; if this is the case price will show 0gp and the 'Buyout' button will be grayed out.

Option C) is still a possibility, if you searched for *Items* and entered the name in the legendary box at bottom - this will search on specific crafted stuff, not the plans themselves! So for e.g., if you search for `Asheara's Clasp` (lvl 51 set gloves) this is different from `Plan: Asheara's Bindings` that you will find in the right place on **Pages & Recipes** section.

[image: Harvest Moon plan on AH (US)]

*Harvest Moon plan on AH*